# Google Webfont Accent Characters (Diacritics) rendering

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts

Google webfonts like Open Sans and Oswald are looking weird on my website. The characters with accents don't show up in the open sans font, but in another font-family. The strange thing is that the same text looks ok on the Google Webfont test page. Also the problem seems to be only on some browsers. The worst is on Opera.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using to get the webfont? Did you make sure that you are including the extended character set?

Comment: Can you please post sample code that demonstrates the issue? This is not simply a symptom of missing glyphs in the font, since e.g. normal letters like “A” appear both in a serif font and in a sans-serif.

Comment: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> This is the code i include in the header.php file on a wordpress platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. It was the chmod of the containing folder. I have set it to 755 for the folder containing the image and it works now.